# subsonic, mvc and activerecord

Tags: asp.net-mvc, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

i am using subsonic 3.0 and active record with a mysql database
now everything is fine, but i cant seem to create views see example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(contact.GetPaged(1,20));
    }
```

now normally i would right click and choose Add View
i would then choose strongly typed and find the class for the repositary

however for some reason the only classes i get showing up are for subsonic only
but expect to see the new class from the new generated graniteMysqlDB

if anyone could please advice i would be most grateful as there doesent seem to be
any forum links or anything for subsonic.

thanks

Comment: Where is your SubSonic generated code, is it in the same assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay i have solved the problem, but the answer is here should anyone need it or wants to know what happened.

i put my TT files into the models folder, my namesspace should have been test2.Models

however it was test2

also i needed the using directive of using test2.Models; at the top of my page.

still get an error where i have to correct the view on the inherites it puts 
i have to change this to

very nice now is this subsonic very very fast loading compared to other stuff i have used.

ta