# Subsonic 3.0.0.3: issues with load slowdowns

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I'm using subsonic 3.0.0.3 (active record) quite a simple database really, have trusted in its abilities but i am really getting let down by how incredibly slow it it to do anything.

For some reason it likes to run through things more than once.
For example:

```
var newitem = new new_quote_item
{
  quote_id = Convert.ToInt32(newQuoteID),
  isextra = true,
  qty = qty,
  measureX = 0,
  measureY = 0,
  prodid = Convert.ToInt32(prodid)
};

newitem.Save();
// claculate price and add to total
var iteminfo = extra.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == Convert.ToInt32(prodid));
```

that will run twice, but inside extra ( the subsonic classes) this can be 3 or 4 loops, really should it be able to create this class once? Why does it have to be initialized, then initialized all over again.

Has anyone had this kind of trouble before? 
It shouldn't take 20 mins to get back a simple quote.

Thanks

Comment: i have managed to get it down to 25 seconds  after publishing the site and putting up a compiled version, this sounds fast and though it is an improvement 20 seconds is considerably slow for what im asking it to do!

Comment: There's something very wrong here. I can't see why there would be more than 2 sql queries at most executed by that code and both of them should be complete in under a second. Can you post the sql that is executed when running just the code you've posted above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing 2 things here:
1) Saving a new class
2) Pulling the record back out.

This will result in two queries - one to INSERT, the other to SELECT. There are no "loops" and I have no idea what you're saying about 3 or 4 loops and "creating the class once". You write the code - you have the object already.

Ad far as 20 minutes goes - that's not SubSonic my friend. As you noted here
[subsonic, mvc and activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296447/subsonic-mvc-and-activerecord/1296581#1296581)

SubSonic is pretty quick and won't take 20 seconds. Check the memory on your server.

Comment: i think my problem may be with the amount of inserts i have as i am creating the whole quote at once and adding each item as needed, and getting the price for each too, im sure you did something called batch update or insert into subsonic got any good pointers on this ????   thanks